# Using top to see processes run by a user on behalf of sudo

Tags: process, top

If I run `top -u username` I will see all the processes by a particular user.  Is there a way to also see all the processes that the user called via sudo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible in an easy way.

From `top`'s perspective, any command a user runs using `sudo` would appear to be running as `root` because it really is running as root.

One way you could try, is to track it down to the terminal where the user is logged in, then see processes running as root on that terminal.

For example,

```
$ w user
USER     TTY      FROM        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user     pts/0    w.x.y.z     07:01    0.00s  1.07s  0.03s w user
```

Note the user is on `pts/0`.

Now run `top`.

Now press <kbd>f</kbd> (field select), then <kbd>g</kbd> (toggle controlling tty field), then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now watch for processes with `pts/0` in the `TTY` column.

You can also sort by `TTY` by pressing <kbd>g</kbd> a second time.

---

Or you could use `procfs` to get a list of `pids`, e.g.

```
$ sudo grep -l SUDO_USER="\<user\>" /proc/*/environ
```

Then do anything with that list.  Even use it to run `top -p <pid1>,<pid2>...`.

```
sudo top -p $(sudo grep -l SUDO_USER='\<user\>' /proc/[0-9]*/environ |
    cut -f 3 -d / |
    tr '\n' ',' |
    sed -e 's/,$//')
```

Of course, in that case, `top` won't show you if that user starts a new command using `sudo`.

---

Also don't forget that a user running a command is probably being logged, e.g. to `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log`, or `/var/log/sudo.log`, or whatever your system uses.

Comment: remember that `sudo -u` starts the subprocess with a uid of the given user, not as root; you would want to limit based on that user.

Comment: Actually, at least in Linux even sudo command is shown under target user (so, for example under root). So ps is not going to help.

Comment: It is possible under `ps` using the same method I just described for `top`: filter based on `TTY` (i.e. `ps -t <tty>`).

Answer (score 0):

You could install [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) and see if it gives you a better overview.
htop supports filtering by user as well.